# help in APNs pem creation

Tags: iphone, linux, apple-push-notifications

after exporting to p.12 in MacOSX, can i run the following 3 step in Linux? Or i must get it done in the same machine where i export to P.12 before i upload to Linux server to use with my php script?

```
openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out apns-dev-cert.pem -in apns-dev-cert.p12
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out apns-dev-key.pem -in apns-dev-key.p12
openssl rsa -in apns-dev-key.pem -out apns-dev-key-noenc.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this might be helpful:

1) [CertificateCreation](http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/wiki/CertificateCreation)

2) [apple-push-notification-service-tutorial](http://ameyashetti.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/apple-push-notification-service-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem in use the openssl in a linux machine. The algorithm is the same.

I used this tutorial and works great: http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/